# Rails best practice for displaying partial if condition is true

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

In my **controller**, I'm getting all of a user's associated @highinterest accounts, and I'm adding the sum of the value column:

```
@dohighinterest = Account.where(user_id: current_user, accounttype: 'Savings', name: ['GE Capital Bank', 'Barclays', 'CIT Bank', 'Bank5 Connect', 'Ally Bank', 'Discover', 'First Choice Bank', 'FNBO Direct', 'Mutual of Omaha', 'Sallie Mae Bank', 'American Express Bank', 'Capital One 360'])

@highinterest = @dohighinterest.sum(&:value)
```

Later on in the controller, I'm defining variables so that the view knows which class to render.

```
if @highinterest > (@rechighinterest * 0.8) && (@highinterest < (@rechighinterest * 1.2))
  @highrec = "pass"
elsif @highinterest > (@rechighinterest * 0.6) && (@highinterest < (@rechighinterest * 1.4))
  @highrec = "okay"
else
  @highrec = "fail"
end
```

Here's the view:

```
<div class="rollup <%= @highrec %>">
    <p>You're gaining interest on</p>
    <div class="percentage">
    $<%= number_with_delimiter(@highinterest, :delimiter => ',') %>
    </div>
</div>
```

Additionally, **I'd like to render a partial in the view if @highrec = "fail" and @highinterest = 0**.

What's the best practice for putting that logic into the controller and view? I attempted to define a new variable in the controller @rectext = true if it meets that condition. Then in the view, I wrapped the partial reference to an <%= if @rectext = true %>, but that wasn't returning anything.

Comment: Did you mean `@rectext == true` which is testing a boolean value rather than the assignment operator `=` which you wrote?

Comment: Also make sure to remove the equals sign in your embedded ruby code for the if statement (`<% if @rectext = true %>` instead of `<%= if @rectext = true %>`). `<%= some_ruby %>` displays the output of whatever's inside of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you need a separate variable to hold value of `@highrec == "fail" && @highinterest == 0`.  You can use this same condition in your view.  If however there are more variables in play, you could introduce a variable to keep the view cleaner!

```
<% if @highrec == "fail" && @highinterest == 0 %>
  <%= render partial: 'path_to_other_partial' %>
<% else %>
  <div class="rollup <%= @highrec %>">
    <p>You're gaining interest on</p>
    <div class="percentage">
    $<%= number_with_delimiter(@highinterest, :delimiter => ',') %>
    </div>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

The line you tried `<%= if @rectext = true %>` would result in syntax error because of `<%=` tag, which is trying to output the value returned by `if @rectext = true`.  So, a point to note would be, using `<%=` tag is going to output the value returned by the statements within the tags and `<%`(without the equals) is going to evaluate only without printing!

Secondly, you are assigning `@rectext = true` in the `if` statement, it should be a comparision, i.e. either `if @rectext == true` or just `if @rectext`.

Answer (score 0):

You can define a helper method inside folder *app/helpers/controllername_helper.rb* that recieves the values of @highrec and @highinterest  as parameters and then returns true or false depending on your needs.

Then in the view call the method this way:

```
 <% if helper_method_name(@highrec, @highinterest) %>
     <%= render partial: 'partial_path' %>
 <% end %>
```

Note that in this code you write :

```
 <%= if @rectext = true %>
```

you are assigning @rectext the value true and not checking if it is true. Also in this case you should use **<%** instead of **<%=**